# Adding custom condition in S3 bucket policy

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Is there any way to add a custom user-defined condition on a S3 bucket policy?
For instance, using the AWS SDK, I can put user metadata in `ObjectMetadata` by using `addUserMetadata(String key, String value)`. I want to be able to enforce a condition involving this customer user metadata via the bucket policy.

For instance:

I first add a user metadata `addUserMetadata("custom-param", "1234")`.

Then later, I want to enforce that this header exists in the bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PutObjPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awslogs.playground/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "x-amz-meta-custom-param": "1234"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The above policy would give me an error "Policy has an invalid condition key".

I think the above error means that S3 bucket policies can only support limited keys. However, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to constrain custom metadata in IAM policies.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#object-keys-in-amazon-s3-policies

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html

Comment: I think we can get around this by using object tagging, but the documentation states that object tags should not include any confidential information.

Comment: @mrQWERTY access control for tags is only available for restricting what you get `GET`, not what you can `PUT`.